# How do I stop a Python process instantly from a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, inject

I have a Python GUI that I use to test various aspects of my work. Currently I have a "stop" button which kills the process at the end of each test (there can be multiple tests set up to run at once). However, some tests take a long time to run and if I need to stop the test I would like it to stop instantly. My thoughts are to use

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
exit
```

But I'm not sure how I would inject this into the next run line of code. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to stop a python process or a python thread?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a thread, you can use the lower-level `thread` (or `_thread` in Python 3) module to kill the thread with an exception by calling `thread.exit()`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.exit):

- thread.exit(): Raise the [SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) exception. When not caught,
  this will cause the thread to exit silently.

---

A cleaner method (depending on how your processing is set up) would be to signal the thread to stop processing and exit using an instance variable, then calling the [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method from your main thread to wait until the thread exits.

Example:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_req = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_req:
            pass
            # processing

        # clean up before exiting

    def stop(self):
        # triggers the threading event
        self._stop_req = True;

def main():
    # set up the processing thread
    processing_thread = MyThread()
    processing_thread.start()

    # do other things

    # stop the thread and wait for it to exit
    processing_thread.stop()
    processing_thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is NOT a good example of the purpose of threading.Event.  That class is for communicating between threads using the wait method, generally not signaling exits.  In this case a simple instance variable would work just fine.

Comment: @Genome: Updated the answer accordingly