# How do I terminate selected threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a code where in I have two types of threads. 3 threads are spawned from the second. I wanted to know if there is a function which I can call, which will terminate the three spawned threads of the second type but still keeping the first one running.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11940400/369977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to have a global variable that the threads check if they should terminate or not.

**Edit:** An example of one way of doing it:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.keep_running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            # Do stuff

my_thread = MyThread()
my_thread.start()

# Do some other stuff

my_thread.keep_running = False
my_thread.join()
```

Comment: How can this check be done dynamically, as an interrupt. Basically I will be creating a webpage where if a user presses a button it will send a HTTP GET to terminate all the threads of the second type.

Comment: @sHoM Added a small example to hopefully give you an idea.

Comment: @sHoM Don't have to be, in that case you don't have to do the call to `join` and of course if your program exits there is no way for you to kill those threads.

Comment: I did the exact same thing as above but it does not leave the While loop but continues the same operations within the while.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a thread pool for each type of thread and then terminate them accordingly. For instance, you can keep them in a `Queue.Queue` globally and then `.stop()` each as needed.

Edit// You can join every child thread you wish to stop to its parent with [`.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

Comment: I need one function that will terminate them all no matter in which state they are.

Comment: You can join them to their parent and kill the parent (see my edit)